# Currency rate update Stop , Cannot convert anymore since 2015-03-04

Tags: odoo, currency

Since march 5 2015, we cannot convert anymore.

The service that we used is Yahoo.

Is there something wrong?

2015-03-02 04:32:35 currency updated.

2015-03-03 04:33:24 currency updated.

2015-03-04 04:33:07 currency updated.

2015-03-05 04:47:25 ERROR : could not convert string to float: N/A

2015-03-06 04:33:22 ERROR : could not convert string to float: N/A

2015-03-07 04:33:12 ERROR : 'Yahoo_getter' object has no attribute 'MOD_NAME'

2015-03-08 04:33:14 ERROR : could not convert string to float: N/A

2015-03-09 04:33:28 ERROR : could not convert string to float: N/A

Answer (score 0):

After some google searching - there seems to some information at the 
[link here](https://github.com/OCA/account-financial-tools/issues/179) that may help you